# Terraform EC2 Instance is not available for SSH after succesful TF apply (unless SSH configs)

Tags: terraform

I am having this code built for example purposes, but however I configure it, the EC2 instance does not become SSHable via the settings provided by EC2 itself albeit it says it should be able to connect. Using tf v0.13.1

This is my TF code:

```
resource "aws_instance" "live" {
  ami = "ami-060e472760062f83f"
  instance_type = "t2.nano"
  key_name = "xxx"

  subnet_id = aws_subnet.default.id
  vpc_security_group_ids =  [
    aws_security_group.http-group.id,
    aws_security_group.https-group.id,
    aws_security_group.ssh-group.id,
    aws_security_group.all-outbound-traffic.id,
  ]

  depends_on = [
    aws_internet_gateway.gw,
    aws_network_interface.default
  ]
}
```

Networking setup:

```
resource "aws_security_group" "https-group" {
  name        = "https-access-group"
  description = "Allow traffic on port 443 (HTTPS)"

  tags = {
    Name = "HTTPS Inbound Traffic Security Group"
  }

  ingress {
    from_port = 443
    to_port   = 443
    protocol  = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]

  }
}


resource "aws_security_group" "http-group" {
  name        = "http-access-group"
  description = "Allow traffic on port 80 (HTTP)"

  tags = {
    Name = "HTTP Inbound Traffic Security Group"
  }

  ingress {
    from_port = 80
    to_port   = 80
    protocol  = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]

  }
}

resource "aws_security_group" "all-outbound-traffic" {
  name        = "all-outbound-traffic-group"
  description = "Allow traffic to leave the AWS instance"

  tags = {
    Name = "Outbound Traffic Security Group"
  }

  egress {
    from_port = 0
    to_port   = 0
    protocol  = "-1"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
}

resource "aws_security_group" "ssh-group" {
  name        = "ssh-access-group"
  description = "Allow traffic to port 22 (SSH)"

  tags = {
    Name = "SSH Access Security Group"
  }

  ingress {
    description = "SSH to VPC"
    from_port   = 22
    to_port     = 22
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  egress {
    from_port = 0
    to_port = 0
    protocol = "-1"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
}


resource "aws_vpc" "default" {
  cidr_block = "10.0.0.0/16"
  enable_dns_support   = true
}

resource "aws_subnet" "default" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.default.id
  cidr_block = "10.0.10.0/24"
}

resource "aws_internet_gateway" "gw" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.default.id
}


resource "aws_eip_association" "eip_assoc" {
  depends_on = [
    aws_instance.live,
    aws_eip.lb
  ]
  instance_id = aws_instance.live.id
  allocation_id = aws_eip.lb.id
  #network_interface_id = aws_network_interface.multi-ip.id
}

resource "aws_eip" "lb" {
  vpc = true
  instance = aws_instance.live.id

  depends_on = [
    aws_instance.live
  ]
}

resource "aws_network_interface" "default" {
  subnet_id       = aws_subnet.default.id
  security_groups = [
    aws_security_group.all-outbound-traffic.id,
    aws_security_group.http-group.id,
    aws_security_group.https-group.id,
    aws_security_group.ssh-group.id
  ]
}
```

And Route53 Setup:

```
    resource "aws_route53_zone" "default" {
      name = "xxx.io."

      vpc {
        vpc_id = aws_vpc.default.id
      }
    }

    resource "aws_route53_record" "x-www" {
      zone_id = aws_route53_zone.default.zone_id
      name = "www.xxx.io"
      type = "A"
      ttl = "300"
      records = [aws_eip.lb.public_ip]
    }

    resource "aws_route53_record" "x-sub-www" {
      zone_id = aws_route53_zone.default.zone_id
      name = "*.xxx.io"
      type = "A"
      ttl = "300"
      records = [aws_eip.lb.public_ip]
    }
```

In AWS console, everything seems connected well together, however the local exec that is in the tf as well is not able to SSH into the EC2 instance and neither am I. What I am doing wrong?

But the instance still remains uncallable via SSH. The Instances are getting built correctly tho and in EC2 Console it all seems to be setup correctly:

[image]

Security Groups are set correctly to EC2 Instance:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have created the security group which is correct but not attached to your ec2 instance hence never opening the port 22 on that instance.

use this :

```
resource "aws_network_interface_sg_attachment" "sg_attachment" {
  security_group_id    = aws_security_group.ssh-group.id
  network_interface_id = aws_instance.live.primary_network_interface_id
}
```

Similarly attach other security groups too...

Comment: I think it must be primary_network_interface_id instead of network_interface_id, no?

Comment: I added it to my code, but SSH is still not available sadly on the internal compute DNS domain that the EC2 shows.

Comment: You set associate_public_ip_address = false, and in lifecycle ignore changes too. Change these. elastic IP should be attached to EC2 if you are using that to ssh. Make sure they are getting attached to instance

Comment: Thanks, I did that yesterday night already, but no difference sadly. The EC2 instance is still unreachable.

Comment: can you share screen shot of aws console of ec2 instance or more information of the ec2 instance that was created using aws cli. Also share the error when you ssh. If you are not getting any error that means you instance is not reachable. If you are getting error then the ssh private key is wrong and you need to fix that

Comment: Sure, I will post the screenshot to the original question. The error is: connection timed out. I ssh'd previously into that container before adding further settings with VPC and Route53, so that worked already before.

Comment: I can see public ip address attached and security group attached which are correct. Possible problems internet gateway not setup properly, verify the public IP  and ssh private key is correct. You can verify internet gateway settings by trying to connect with aws console using Ec2 instance connect.

Comment: refer to this doc https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-linux-resolve-ssh-connection-errors/